# What does the phrase 「やのう」 mean?

Tags: words, kansai-ben

I came across the phrase in the following sentence.

> ええ度{ど}胸{きょう}**やのう**こまいの...けなげやで

The guy who said it is a Kansai speaker. I'm not sure if the phrase is related to the dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is western Japan dialect which is equivalent to だなあ in standard Japanese.

It's a part of Kansai dialect in the broader sense, but I think this のう is not very common in typical Kansai-ben spoken in Osaka. AFAIK It's mainly used in Chugoku/Shioku, which is located further west from Osaka.

Comment: 私が馴染みのある中では[広島弁](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%83%E5%B3%B6%E5%BC%81)か[讃岐弁](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AE%83%E5%B2%90%E5%BC%81)が最も近いのですが、他の地方でも使われているかもしれません。